# IBM CPLEX - Warehouse location CP

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, constraint-programming, ilog, operations-research

I'm trying to run the [scalablewarehouse](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/scalablewarehouse.mod) example from IBM, with the CP algorithm, but when I add the `using CP;` to the mod file, I get an error on this line:

```
dvar float Supply[Stores][Warehouses] in 0..1;
```

And the error:

> Decision variables of type dvar float not supported by this algorithm.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/ see CPO with decimal decision variables https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoodecimalcpo.mod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Easy optimization](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) see [CPO with decimal decision variables](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoodecimalcpo.mod)

```
using CP;
{int} Warehouses = {1,2,3,4};
int NbStores = 5;
range Stores = 0..NbStores-1;

int scale=100;
dvar int scaleSupply[Stores][Warehouses] in 0..scale;

dexpr float supply[s in Stores][w in Warehouses] = scaleSupply[s][w]/scale;

subject to
{
  supply[1][1]==0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can fix it simply. I don't think the CP optimiser supports float variables. You could try scaling those numbers that are supposed to be continuous and handle them as e.g. percentages using integer variables with a range of 0 to 100.